# Sharepoint hide ribbon for standard users

Tags: sharepoint, ribbon

is it possible to hide te ribbon for standard users in Sharepoint ?
I want to see the ribbon when I am a administrator, but what I want is that people can only add a document and not do edit in the ribbon.

Comment: What version of SharePoint and what is a standard user, please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has no standard way (configuration) to hide Ribbon only for selected users. You can use javascript, maybe jQuery to do it. Ribbon is rendered into <div id="RibbonContainer">.

You can get info about current user via javascript client object model. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410544%28v=office.14%29.aspx).